# Fundamental Groups of a Simplicial Complex and the Underlying Space

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Now I know how the fundamental group of a Simplicial Complex is defined, as well as that of a Toplogical Space. Could someone explain the process of how we prove that for a simplicial complex $X$ , how $\pi_1(X)$ and $\pi_1(|X|)$ are isomorphic?

Comment: Since combinatorial loops give real loops in $|X|$, and since $2$-cells are contractible in the geometric realization, you should be able to build a morphism $\pi_1(X)\to \pi_1(|X|)$ (of course it remains to show that it is an isomorphism).

Comment: I'm having trouble with the homotopy part (making the homomorphism well defined), could you explain that?

Comment: Use simplicial approximation theorem.